# Script to save bash output to YAML file

Tags: bash, yaml

I can output the relevant details of my printer using the command line:
`sed -En 's/[ \t]*b?(id[vp][^ \t]*|endpoint)(address)?[ \t]+([^ \t]*).* (out|in)?.*/\l\1\4 (\3)/Ip' <(lsusb | awk '$0 ~ /STMicroelectronics printer-80/{print $6}' | xargs -I % sh -c "lsusb -vvv -d %")`
outputs:

```
idVendor (0x0483)
idProduct (0x5743)
endpointOUT (0x01)
endpointIN (0x81)
```

Now, I need to save those data to a YAML file in the following format:

```
printer:
        type: Usb
        idVendor: 0x0483
        idProduct: 0x5743
        in_ep: 0x81
        out_ep: 0x01
```

I just don’t know how to achieve this formatting and save to the file.

I‘ve tried formatting the output, but couldn’t get further than this snippet.

Comment: There might be easier ways to get where you want to be if you clicked [edit] and added the relevant part of the `lsusb` command before your `sed` manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reformats each line:

```
sed -E 's/(.*) \((.*)\)/    \1: \2/g' <<< "idVendor (0x0483)"
```

result:

```yaml
    idVendor: 0x0483
```

Combine this with your previous command and prepend the `printer:` line to get the desired output:

```bash
echo "printer:" > file.yaml
sed -En 's/[ \t]*b?(id[vp][^ \t]*|endpoint)(address)?[ \t]+([^ \t]*).* (out|in)?.*/\l\1\4 (\3)/Ip' \
    <(lsusb | awk '$0 ~ /STMicroelectronics printer-80/{print $6}' | \
      xargs -I % sh -c "lsusb -vvv -d %"\
    ) | sed -E 's/(.*) \((.*)\)/    \1: \2/g' >> file.yaml
```

It is unclear how you want to get the line `type: Usb`, you can of course just write it into the file like `printer:`. As for the different names, simply append `sed -e 's/endpointOUT/out_ep/' -e s/endpointIN/in_ep/'`.

Comment: Genius! Just one more thing occurred... sometimes the output includes an error message: "can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable" and
"can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable". Is it possible to filter out any line starting with "can't" (bad practice hack maybe, but if it works...?) @flyx

Comment: Easiest way to filter out lines is probably `grep -Ev "^can't"`, `-v` selects all lines that do not match.